# Finding specific number inside a string?

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-2007

This is a sample of my data, where `name` is in cell `A1`. The column C is not part of the data, it is there just to illustrate what is wanted.

```
name    cod     should be detected?
aa              no  
aa      14;15   no
aa      1;13;7  yes 
bb      8;9;1   yes 
bb      1;17    yes 
bb      11;21   no
cz      7;8     no  
cz      7;21    no
cz      8;1;20  yes 
db      1       yes 
db      13;1    yes
```

I am trying to write a macro to detect on the column `cod` where the number 1 appears. For example, I don't want to find 10, 13, 21, but `1`. The filled in numbers on this column go from 1 to 21.

All `cod` values are strings, but I want to find where there is `1`, even if it appears mixed with other numbers in the string. Numbers in this column are always separated with `;` without white spaces in between.

The following code will produce false **positives**:

```
Dim N As Range
Dim msg As String

Sub cod1()

msg = ""

For Each N In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    If InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                msg = msg & "Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column." & vbLf
            Exit For
    End If
Next N

    If Len(msg) > 1 Then
        MsgBox msg
    Else: MsgBox "There are no code 1 values in Cod column."
    End If

End Sub
```

See results:

```
name    cod     should be detected? problem
aa              no  
aa      14;15   no                  false positive
aa      1;13;7  yes 
bb      8;9;1   yes 
bb      1;17    yes 
bb      11;21   no                  false positive
cz      7;8     no  
cz      7;21    no                  false positive
cz      8;1;20  yes 
db      1       yes 
db      13;1    yes
```

The following code will produce false **negatives**:

```
Dim N As Range
Dim msg As String

Sub cod2()

msg = ""

For Each N In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    If InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 1, vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 10, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 11, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 12, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 13, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 14, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 15, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 16, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 17, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 18, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 19, vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        InStr(1, N.Offset(, 1), 21, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            msg = msg & "Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column." & vbLf
        Exit For
    End If
Next N

    If Len(msg) > 1 Then
        MsgBox msg
    Else: MsgBox "There are no code 1 values in Cod column."
    End If

End Sub
```

See results:

```
name    cod     should be detected? problem
aa              no  
aa      14;15   no  
aa      1;13;7  yes                 false negative
bb      8;9;1   yes 
bb      1;17    yes                 false negative
bb      11;21   no  
cz      7;8;10  no  
cz      7;21    no  
cz      8;1;20  yes                 false negative
db      1       yes 
db      13;1    yes                 false negative
```

So, how could one make the message box* appear only when a number `1` is detected inside the string?

> *Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column.

---

<sub>Looking for a solution that works with Excel 2007 and newer versions.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Like` operator to find the characters:

```
Dim N As Range
Dim msg As String

Sub cod1()

    Dim expression As String
    msg = ""

    For Each N In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        expression = ";" & N.Offset(, 1) & ";"
        If expression Like "*;1;*" Then
           msg = msg & "Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column." & vbLf
        End If
    Next N

    If Len(msg) > 1 Then
        MsgBox msg
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no code 1 values in Cod column."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: All 3 answers (ThunderFrame, A.S.H and EEM), which had different approaches, worked nice in my sample and actual data (+1 for all of them). Then, I am accepting this one because the structure of the code was similar to what I was already using.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can have a generic UDF (User-Defined Function) that detects the existence of any value inside a cell, using any separator:

```
Public Function hasItem(ByVal r As Range, item As Variant, sep As String) As Boolean
    ar = Split(r.Text, sep)
    For Each x In ar
        If Trim(CStr(x)) = Trim(CStr(item)) Then
           hasItem = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Put the above UDF in code Module `Module1`, and use it like this in your cells of column `C`, i.e. in `C1`:

```
=IF(hasItem(B1, 1, ";"), "yes", "no")
```

Then you can copy/paste it in all of the `C` cells.
Also, you can use the function conveniently in any VBA code to display the messages you want.

Answer (score 1):

This solutions uses the `Split` function to generate an array of values in column `B` then compares each array item.

```
Sub Test()
Dim rDta As Range, rRow As Range
Dim aRow As Variant, vItm As Variant
Dim sMsg As String, lRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA.3").Cells(1).CurrentRegion   'change as required
        Set rDta = .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
    End With

    lRow = 1
    For Each rRow In rDta.Rows
        lRow = 1 + lRow
        aRow = Split(rRow.Cells(2).Value2, ";")
        For Each vItm In aRow
            If vItm = 1 Then
                If sMsg = vbNullString Then sMsg = "Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column of rows:"
                    sMsg = sMsg & vbLf & vbTab & lRow
                rRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Code 1 was not supposed to be in Cod column." 'Remove if required
    End If: Next: Next

    If sMsg = vbNullString Then sMsg = "There are no code 1 values in Cod column."
    MsgBox sMsg

End Sub
```